# Quality of the voice in Twilio Android demo application

Tags: twilio

I try implementing the Twilio Android demo application (HelloMonkey). The tutorial is very good for following. But I meet some issues:

```
   + The voice is delayed about 1 second when talking
   + The voice is repeated when talking
```

Do I meet the issues because I'm using trial account ? How to improve quality of the voice, do I have a premium account to check real quality of the voice ?

Please help me answer the questions.

Thanks,
Quan Dang

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

You should not need to upgrade in order to have a high-quality experience using Twilio Client.  Since problems like this tend to be difficult to debug here on Stack Overflow, I'd suggest sending an email to our support team (help@twilio.com).  If you can, try to include a few SID's of calls that experienced the problem so they can dig into those.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I sent a email to help@twilio.com and waiting for the reply. I tested the app in Vietnam and Japan, does quality of voice depend on area